# Exact sequence that splits

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

**Problem**: Let $(1)\quad 0\to \mathfrak a\to R\to R/\mathfrak a\to 0$ be an exact sequence. Show that if there exists $e\in\mathfrak a$ such that $e^2=e$ and $\mathfrak a=Re$, then $(1)$ splits.

**Question**: The proof is straightforward: let $k:R\to R/\mathfrak a$ be the canonical isomorphism. Consider $\sigma:R/\mathfrak a\to R$; $r+\mathfrak a\mapsto (1-r)e$. Then $\sigma$ is a section of $k$. Thus, $(1)$ splits.

But aren't we supposed to have $k\sigma=1_{R/\mathfrak a}$? I don't see why this proof works. Any insight? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably easier to define $R \to \mathfrak a$ such that $r \mapsto re$. It's easy to verify the property you seek since $e^2 = e$.

Comment: I do not quite see how $\sigma$ is well defined: For some $s\in R$ it sends $r+se$ to $(1-(r+se))e = (1-r)e - se^2 = (1-r)e - se = (1-(r+s))e$ which is not equal to the image of $r$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh But, then, how do I get $\rho\iota=1_{\mathfrak a}$, where $\rho$ is the map you suggested and $\iota$ is the inclusion $\mathfrak a\hookrightarrow R$? To show that it splits, I either find a retraction of $\iota$ or a section of $k$.

Comment: @XuguiManuel As $\mathfrak a = Re$, to prove that $\rho \iota = 1_{\mathfrak a}$ (i.e. $\rho$ restricted to $\mathfrak a$ is the identity) you just need to prove that $\rho(re)=re$ for all $r \in R$. Can you do that?

Comment: @azif00 Yes of course. I was thinking of it all wrong. I was reading identity, but thinking it all mapped to $1$. Sorry for my distraction.

Comment: Posted an answer to remove the question from the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varphi : R \to \mathfrak a$ such that $\varphi(r) = re$. This homomorphism is well defined since $\mathfrak a = Re$. Let $\iota : \mathfrak a \to R$ be the inclusion homomorphism.

Consider $a \in \mathfrak a$. Since $\mathfrak a = Re$, we can find $r \in R$ such that $a = re$. We have:
$$
(\varphi \circ \iota)(a) = \varphi(re) = re^2 = re = a.
$$

Thus, $\varphi \circ \iota = 1_\mathfrak a$ as desired.